# How can i add an image as background in Chartjs?

Tags: background, background-image, chart.js

I am using chart.js lib on a programmable device i need to add an image as background to my chart, if that is not possible how can i change background color to black?. I cannot use Jquery as it is not supported by the Platform.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style the canvas element. Something like this will work

```
canvas {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/w1yhp03h/

Answer (score 6):

Thank you!

I didn't think to CSS, i added an image too in a similar way

```
canvas {
   background-image: url(backgroundimage.jpg);
}
```

Comment: cheers! I was pretty sure you'd figure that one out easily once you got the idea you could use CSS. I was hunting for an image to make a fiddle and then gave it up :-)

Comment: Only problem with this approach is that the background image is not copied with the chart, so copying the image ends up withouth it.