# Chart.js 3.3.0 - Draw text on top of chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am very new to JS and I am building a chart using Chart.js v3. I'm looking for a way to put bits of text at specific x,y coordinates on the chart, independent of any data points. I've seen some solutions for previous versions of chart.js, [like this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567325/add-background-text-in-chartjs/57567643), but haven't been able to get it to work.

Is there any way of achieving this through chart.js, or will I have to manually add text elements to the canvas?

Comment: Please include your research and/or coding effort. Without it, your question is *off-topic* here. See [ask]. This [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) might also help.

Comment: The way to go about it is to create a new chart type, by extending an existing chart, following [this example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/developers/charts.html#extending-existing-chart-types) and, in its custom `draw()` function place the text where you want it. Note `draw()` has access to context, therefore to the entire canvas element, allowing you to place text where you want. Then you simply add a new data series to the dataset and give it this custom `type` and your text should show up. If you want the text to be dynamic and come from the dataset, you can do that as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best thing to do is write a custom plugin where you can put the text on the canvas, chart.js doesnt provide this functionallity out of the box

Example:

```js
const customText = {
  id: 'customText',
  afterDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
    const {
      ctx,
      canvas
    } = chart;
    textObjects = options.text;

    if (textObjects.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    textObjects.forEach((textObj) => {
      ctx.save();

      ctx.textAlign = textObj.textAlign || 'center';
      ctx.font = `${textObj.size || '20px'} ${textObj.font || 'Arial'}`;
      ctx.fillStyle = textObj.color || 'black'
      ctx.fillText(textObj.text, textObj.x, textObj.y)

      ctx.restore();
    })
  }
}

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      customText: {
        text: [{
            text: 'Lorem ipsum',
            x: 300,
            y: 150,
            textAlign: 'center',
            size: '30px',
            color: 'black',
            font: 'Arial black'
          },
          {
            text: 'Lorem ipsum2',
            x: 300,
            y: 250,
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: 'red',
            font: 'Arial black'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [customText]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I really appreciate your help.